# Calculating difference between max and min date for the specific value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe with max and min date and the value('price') - the values can be grouped by third column (let's say 'category'). How can the difference between price between max and min date be calculated using Pandas for each of the categories? Do I need groupby for that or it can be achieved using index?

[image]

So that it will be 783.44 for category A and 5.08 for category B

Thanks!

Comment: Please put your sample dataframe as text, not an image, and add expected output

Comment: provided it so I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
        date    price category
0 2018-06-03  7632.09        a
1 2018-06-03   123.29        a
2 2018-04-05  6848.65        a
3 2018-04-05   118.21        a


df2 = (df.groupby(['category', 'date'])['price']
         .agg(['max','min'])
         .add_prefix('_')
         .eval('_max - _min')
         .reset_index(name='diff'))
print (df2)
  category       date     diff
0        a 2018-04-05  6730.44
1        a 2018-06-03  7508.80
```

Comment: I think you can also add the first version with sort_values() and 'last'-'first' it is also very clear :)